# Fix Login issues tapatalk with joomla 1.5 to phpbb3 bridge

Tags: joomla, authentication, phpbb

I have a forum that I want to integrate tapatalk into.
Everything works except when I login I get the following error message:
http://vps.Midnightfox.be/imagehost/issue_phpbb3bridge.jpg

Does anybody know a way of editing the bridge so logins are allowed with tapatalk ?